# why do I get 0 in the right column of knn classification confusion matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, confusion-matrix

I would like to build a knn model to classify and the dataset that I've used is https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/19/car+evaluation

My confusion matrix is

```
[[385   0]
 [134   0]]
```

I get a column of 0 in the right of the confusion matrix and my f1 score is 0 as well. My accuracy score, however, was 0.74 I am wondering if it is because I did not convert the results back to categorical after one-hot encoding it. If so, what can I use to revert the results back to categorical?

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

data = pd.read_csv('car.data', sep=",")
data.columns = ['buying', 'maint','doors', 'persons', 'lug_boots', 'safety','class']
data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['buying', 'maint','doors', 'persons', 'lug_boots', 'safety','class'], drop_first=True, dtype=int)
print(data)


print(data)
x = data.iloc[:, 0:6]
y = data.iloc[:, 6]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0, test_size = 0.3)


sc_x = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc_x.transform(x_test)

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=17, p=2, metric='euclidean')
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)

confusionmatrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print(confusionmatrix)

print(f1_score(y_test, y_pred))

print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens when we check the results for a sample with label `1`:

```
classifier.kneighbors(x_test[y_test==1][0].reshape(1, -1), return_distance=True)
```

returns:

> (array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0.]]),
>
> array([[ 98, 307, 154, 294, 149, 152, 431, 288, 147,  70,  15, 109, 156,
> 164, 381,  20,  76]]))

If you check the samples at the returned indices (second array) you would see that they are mostly labelled 0, this is because generally the number of samples with label 0 is much more.

But why does this result in all samples being classified as `0`?
Notice the distance array for the returned neighbours, all distances are zero, that is because there were many other samples with exactly the same feature values and since the features are discrete, the distances are zero.

Going deeper, the underlying cause can be that the dataset is not linearly separable and data points of class `0` are distributed in different points such that they dominate every point in the data space, therefore, for every sample, the majority of neighbours will be `0`.

Here's a little code snippet that shows you how most data are overlaying and overlapping (using only first two features):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# i changed name of column class to cat to avoid reserved names in python
x1 = data.buying[data.cat=='unacc']
x2 = data.buying[data.cat=='good']
x3 = data.buying[data.cat=='vgood']

y1 = data.maint[data.cat=='unacc']
y2 = data.maint[data.cat=='good']
y3 = data.maint[data.cat=='vgood']

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'rx')
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'bx')
plt.plot(x3, y3, 'gx')
```

[image: resulting plot]